# How can I work out what v4l2 driver/module my webcam is using?

Tags: webcam, v4l

I've got a fault with how my webcam is being handled (awful framerate). I'd like to diagnose this and possibly dig into the code but I can't tell which v4l2 driver the thing's actually using.

How do I get v4l2 (or other) to tell me?

Answer (score 1):

`dmesg | tail` was the answer (of course!):

```
[532158.847924] gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
[532158.850325] gspca_main: ov519-2.14.0 probing 054c:0155
[532159.082977] input: ov519 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/input/input18
[532159.083169] usbcore: registered new interface driver ov519
```